# Add dataEmptyMessage in FusionCharts Django

Tags: python, django, charts, fusioncharts

How can I display status and error messages that can be set for any chart in the Django FusionCharts constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use from addMessage method of FusionCharts class:

```
chartObject = FusionCharts(type, id, width, height, renderAt, dataFormat, dataSource)

chartObject.addMessage("dataEmptyMessage", "put your custom text here")
```